# Phusion Passenger - ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, activerecord

I am trying to run simple RoR application with Phusion Passenger. At the moment when go to localhost I see the error from subject. In fact I don't have any pending migration:

```
     Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20150222215652  Create products
   up     20150405145349  Create carts
   up     20150405151313  Create line items
   up     20150407094606  Add quantity to line items
   up     20150409062414  Combine items in cart
   up     20150516084832  Create orders
   up     20150516084958  Add order id to line item
   up     20151005170430  Add ship date to orders
   up     20151011083822  Create users
   up     20151118212158  Add locale to products
```

My platform is Linux (Debian 8 Jessie 64x).

My database is MySQL (gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18').

I am using Ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-linux] and Rails 4.1.8.

Passenger version is 5.0.22.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? What have I missed?

Comment: Maybe someday there was any migration which is deleted now and thus version in schema.rb doesn't match to version of last migration, and that's why Rails think there are pending migrations?

Comment: You can run `rake db:drop; rake db:create;  rake db:migrate`. It will recreate db from scratch

Comment: @hedgesky The error occures only when I access the application through Apache with configured Passenger. I can execute command `rails s` and the application would be accessible through `localhost:3000` without any problem.

Comment: @mef_ I tried to drop manually all MySQL schemas related to the application, than run `rake db:create` and `rake db:migrate`. Nothing changed.

Comment: What was the output when you run these commands?

Comment: Did you run the above command in `development` or `production` environment? In what environment is passenger running?

Comment: @mef_ Command `rake db:create` outputs nothing. Command `rake db:migrate` reports about successfully migrated scripts.

Comment: @spickermann Passenger running in `development` environment (`RailsEnv development` in Apache config). Command `rake db:migrate` creates tables in `development` database.

Comment: Did you double check you are connecting to the same database when using rake and passenger?

Comment: @iltempo I tried to migrate all databases for all environments, but unfortunately it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally my issue is solved. Helped trivial Apache server restart. Knowing the wonderful ability of Rails to apply most of changes on the fly, I didn't even think that Apache would be needed to restart at some point. I did that only after modifying its configuration. Anyway thanks to all who tried to help me.

Comment: Too simple. Rails is not initialising the whole stack on file changes.

Comment: @iltempo `ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError` was raised by `check_pending!` method in `migration.rb` script. So I just decided to comment out body of that method and after that hit refresh button in browser. To my surprise nothing changed. I restarted Apache and error gone. For now changes in `migration.rb` are reverted and Apache was restarted several times. `ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError` does not appear.